# Angular2 Services Injection in Bootstrap

Tags: service, angular, code-injection, provider

Could someone explain me the difference between

```
bootstrap(MyApp, [provide(Service1, { useClass: Service1})]);
```

and

```
bootstrap(MyApp, [Service1]);
```

Comment: Note that the Angular docs now discourage us from registering providers using `bootstrap()`.  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#configuring-the-injector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly the same. You can use it when the token used for the provider is the class itself. If you watnt to provide something else behind the provider token, you can use the `provide` function with `useClass`, `useValue`, `useExisting` or `useFactory`.

Here are some samples that can interest you:

- [Angular 2 - How to get Observable.throw globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439672/angular-2-how-to-get-observable-throw-globally/35439805#35439805)
- [Inject all Services that implement some Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916542/inject-all-services-that-implement-some-interface/)

You could also have a look at the documentation of the `Provider` class:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Provider-class.html

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a difference.

Using this version

```
bootstrap(MyApp, [provide(Service1, { useClass: Service1})]);
```

only makes sense when the classes differ, like

```
bootstrap(MyApp, [provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend})]);
```

to pass a `MockBackend` when an `XHRBackend` is requested (is the type of the constructor parameter.

```
constructor(private backend:XHRBackend) {}
```

would get a `MockBackend` instance passed in.

If you just want to pass `Service1` when `Service1` is requested

```
bootstrap(MyApp, [Service1]);
```

will do.