# Angular2 http retry logic

Tags: javascript, http, angular, rxjs

I have an API with token based authentication mechanism. After successful signin I store two tokens in the browser's local storage - access and refresh token. 
The access token contains all necessary information required to authorize a user on the server side and it has expiration date. 
When the access token is expired the client could request a new access token using refresh token and in the response it will get a pair of new tokens.

In angular 1.x the implementation is pretty simple and straightforward. For instance we could use interceptors:

```
httpInterceptor.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];
function httpInterceptor($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(handleStaleAccessToken);

  handleStaleAccessToken.$inject = ['$q', '$injector', 'session'];
  function handleStaleAccessToken($q, $injector, session) {

    function logoutAndRedirect() {
      var authenticationRedirect = $injector.get('authenticationRedirect');
      session.destroy();
      authenticationRedirect.toLoginPage();
    }

    return {
      responseError: function(rejection) {
        // Do nothing for non 403 errors
        if (rejection.status !== 403) {
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }

        var errorCode = rejection.data.error && rejection.data.error.code;
        if (errorCode === 'access_token_expired') {
          var $http = $injector.get('$http');

          // Refresh token
          var params = { refreshToken: session.getRefreshToken() };
          return $http.post('/api/auth/refresh', params).then(function(response) {
            session.setTokens(response.data);
            // Re try failed http request
            return $http(rejection.config);
          }).catch(function(error) {
            logoutAndRedirect();
            return $q.reject(error);
          });
        } else {
          logoutAndRedirect();
        }

        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

But how to implement similar logic in angular 2 / rxjs app?

Answer (score 7):

This can be done transparently in Angular2 by extending the `Http` class and leveraging observable operators like `flatMap`.

Here is some sample code:

```
if (hasTokenExpired()) {
  return this.authService
             .refreshAuthenticationObservable()
             .flatMap((authenticationResult:AuthenticationResult) => {
                if (authenticationResult.IsAuthenticated == true) {
                     this.authService.setAuthorizationHeader(request.headers);
                  return this.http.request(url, request);
                }
                return Observable.throw(initialError);
    });
}
```

This code must be integrated into a custom sub class of the `Http` one:

An approach could be to extend the HTTP object to intercept errors:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

and register it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

For more details have a look at these questions:

- [Handling refresh tokens using rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907151/handling-refresh-tokens-using-rxjs)
- [Angular 2 - How to get Observable.throw globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439672/angular-2-how-to-get-observable-throw-globally/35439805#35439805)

Comment: Your aproach is the same as mine... The only problem for me is the parallel requests. If I subscribe to 3 different http requests... then every request will have the same token. the first only will invalidate the token, and the other 2 http requests will fail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar in my recent project [shafihuzaib/cdp-ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/shafihuzaib/cdp-ng-boilerplate) and landed on this question for my answer. I couldn't go for the above suggested solution, as it felt complicated and something not desirable. So I came back to leave my solution after I implemented one. However, the difference being that in my case, I had two such tokens.

So, every request that needs to have tokens' validity checked, is called inside this function.

```
tokenValidatedRequest(func): Observable<any>{
    let returnObservable = new Observable();

    /**
     * 1. check for auth token expiry - refresh it, if necessary
     */
    if( parseInt(localStorage.getItem('AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRY')) < (new Date()).valueOf() ){
        //auth expired
        this.refresh().subscribe(res => {
            //refreshed
            //this.postAuthSuccess(res);

             returnObservable = func();

        })
    }
    else{
        //auth not expired

       returnObservable = func();

    }

    return returnObservable;
}
```

The most important thing here is that `func()` should return an `Observable`, so that it can be consumed accordingly.

```
makeSomeHttpCall(){
   this.tokenValidatedRequest(()=>{
       return this.http.post(...);
   }). subscribe();
}
```

It may seem a bit complicated for someone new, but I am sure it is a little more efficient.

In the following links, please ignore the details that are irrelevant to this question and focus on the usage of the suggested solution.

[Actual implementation of `tokenValidatedRequest()` in my project](https://github.com/shafihuzaib/cdp-ng-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/project/services/auth/auth-service.ts#L94-L152).

```
 tokenValidatedRequest(func , tqlCheck = false): Observable<any>{
    /**
     * Delegate the actual task. However return an Observable, so as to execute 
     * the callback function only when subscribed to..
     */
    //return Observable.create(obs => obs = (this.__tokenValidatedRequest(func, tqlCheck)));

    return this.__tokenValidatedRequest(func, tqlCheck);
}
private __tokenValidatedRequest(func, tqlCheck = false): Observable<any>{
    let returnObservable = new Observable();

    /**
     * 1. check for auth token expiry - refresh it, if necessary
     * 2. after step 1 - check for TQL token expiry (if tqlCheck is true) - refresh it, if necessary
     * 3. 
     */
    if( parseInt(localStorage.getItem('AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRY')) < (new Date()).valueOf() ){
        //auth expired
        this.refresh().subscribe(res => {
            //refreshed
            this.postAuthSuccess(res);

            if(tqlCheck &&  localStorage.getItem("TQL_TOKEN_EXPIRY") &&
                    parseInt(localStorage.getItem("TQL_TOKEN_EXPIRY")) < (new Date()).valueOf()
               ){

                this.activateUser().subscribe(res => {
                    //TQL token subscribed 
                    returnObservable = func();
                })
            }
            else{
                // Probably not a TQL request
                returnObservable = func();
            }
        })
    }
    else{
        //auth not expired

        //check if tql token has expired
        if(tqlCheck &&  localStorage.getItem("TQL_TOKEN_EXPIRY") &&
                    parseInt(localStorage.getItem("TQL_TOKEN_EXPIRY")) < (new Date()).valueOf()
               ){

                this.activateUser().subscribe(res => {
                    //TQL token subscribed 
                    returnObservable = func();
                })
            }
            else{
                // Probably not a TQL request or none of the tokens expired
                returnObservable = func();
            }
    }

    return returnObservable;
}
```

[How it is used in other services!](https://github.com/shafihuzaib/cdp-ng-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/project/services/realtime/parking/realtime-parking-service.ts#L33-L35)

```
getAllParkingSpaces() : Observable<any> {
    let query = {
        Query: {
            ....
        }
    };

    return this.authService.tokenValidatedRequest(()=>{
        return this.api.post( CONFIG.api.engineUrl + 'devices/parking', query);
    }, true);
}
```

[How I finally subscribe to it!](https://github.com/shafihuzaib/cdp-ng-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L36-L40)

```
    this.realTimeParkingService.getAllParkingSpaces().subscribe( r => {
  this.parkingSpaces = r;
});
```